# Ruby on Rails: insert javascript into a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So.. I have this in the action called when someone clicks the archive button

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js do
    render :update do |page|
      page << "alert('You have reached your archive object limit. You have #{remaining} remaining archived objects.');"
      end
    end
 end
```

But instead of alerting, it just gets rid of the entire page and shows a JavaScript try / catch with that alert message. How do I just do an alert without rendering anything?

Comment: What does the code look like on the view, where they click the archive button?

Comment: Problem was that I wasn't using a from_remote_tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to change form_for to form_remote_for to enable ajax

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
:layout => false
```

in render

Answer (score 0):

If it's an AJAX call, you may do something like this in your action:

```
render :text => "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('bla');</script>"
```

Comment: it action makes the browser navigate away from the page... so... i added a redirect. but I can only have one